# I need to enter a password again and again in terminal how can I assign it to a variable so that I can use it again and again

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I Need to enter a key again and again on running java file in terminal. How can I assign this key to a variable so that whenever asked I can enter this variable name. Instead of password.

So for example when I enter 'java -jar filename.jar' I get 'Enter Key String' in response. So instead of entering password I want to save my password in variable 'Key' so each time instead of entering password I can just write Key and press enter and my file should run.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are entering this command locally for security reasons, before running the Java command, enter the following,

```
key=(Enter your password here)
echo "$key" | (java -jar filename.jar)
```

So when the Java program asks for input, the `echo` command with the key variable will be entered for you.

Not sure if this will always repeat each time automatically.

Update: You can use the `yes`, `printf`, or `expect` command, which should be able to perform what you are looking for.

Comment: Proper formatting will make your intentions more clear.